# Bounding box as a 4-tuple - south/west/north/east order?

Tags: extents, api

We need to pass a bounding box as a 4-tuple and we cannot pass named arguments. I've searched a bit at found that different APIs use different order of lat/lon and different corners (northwest/southeast and southwest/northeast). What's in fact is a "best practice"?

Comment: It what context? If you deal with GML or other OGC standards small numbers of each axis come first http://www.datypic.com/sc/niem21/e-gml32_boundedBy.html.

Comment: Context - RESTlike APIs. In the request, it could be passed as `?boundingBox=47.065,15.425,47.07,15.43`; in the response we are more flexible in theory.

Comment: Best practice is to use the axis order defined by the CRS you want to use: so for example [EPSG:4326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) is expressed in Lat/Long order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to choose one and make sure its documented.

If you are a geographer, the natural order would probably be to start in the North and go clockwise, like a bearing - so ymax, xmax, ymin, xmin.

If you  are a mathematician, the natural order would be to start at 0 degrees in the X-Y plane and go anticlockwise, which is increasing angle for mathematicians. That gives you xmax, ymax, xmin, ymin.

If you are thinking more of corner coordinates, then go for xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax. such that pairs of numbers form the bottom left and top right coordinates.

I think the lack of an accepted best practice for the order stems from the essentially arbitrary choice of order. Not having a best practice in this case might be a good thing, since people get slack when best practices are accepted and are then caught out when someone does something that is correct - such as choosing a different order and documenting it - but people don't read the docs and assume best practice. Never do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We will definitely follow just one standard across our APIs. Yes, I come from mathematics, but in this case prefer lat/lon myself, we will need to decide which corners to take.